# Can I move a GridSplitter that resizes an IFRAME in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I have a simple Grid control in my silverlight page. One of the cells in the grid is supposed to house a web page. As there is no web browser control, I have added an IFRAME to the HTML page and I modify the size and position of the IFRAME after loading so it looks like it is in the grid cell.

I also have a GridSplitter that I use to allow the user to resize portions of the grid. When the user resizes the grid, the IFRAME is resized also.

All of this works great with one small problem. If I drag the GridSplitter towards the IFRAME, as soon as the mouse pointer is in front of the IFRAME the resizing stops. I guess because the mouse pointer has left the Silverlight control and is now in the HTML area.

Is there any way to modify this so that dragging the GridSplitter over the IFRAME continues the resizing operation?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution, but could you change the z-order of the iframe in the html while it's in drag mode to put it under the silverlight application?

Comment: I tried that but when I change the z-index the iframe disappears. Is there a way to make the Silverlight stuff transparent so it shows through?